# How can i change configuration setting using RoleEnvironmentChanging in Azure

Tags: azure

I have tested with my staging and production applications on azure that if we will swap then configuration doesn't going to be change. Azure will change just DNS entry.

Now what i want to do that if i have added any custom config setting **ServiConfiguration.cscfg** file called

```
 <Setting name="Environment" value="staging" /> OR
 <Setting name="Environment" value="production" />
```

, then i would like to make changes in configuration after swapping using **RoleEnvironmentChanging** event. Is this possible? Or How can i do that?

/Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RoleEnvironmentChanging event is only fired when you change your configuration, not when you do a VIP swap.  At the moment there is no event that is fired when you do a VIP swap so if you want to change the config after doing a VIP swap you'll have to either do it manually in the portal or through the management API as smarx said.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the setting in the portal or via the Service Management API. `RoleEnvironmentChanging` is one of the events that's triggered once you change the setting.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but my problem is that I am using startup task to send perfmon data to database and i want to put restriction(do no send) when startup task running on staging without using management api (need subscription & certificate) and just using with RoleEnvironment Class. Hope that you will get my point!

Comment: Hello Marx I have read about your "CarrerNext" on your blog and joining to "Aditi" and leaving Microsoft. I think you have great plan to build next thing ;) however keep sharing your knowledge about azure. and Best of luck for your journey :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do, but there are only two ways to change config settings: the portal and the Service Management API.